# Key stops repeating randomly

Tags: 16.04

I have a very strange problem: When I hold down a key, it gets repeated for a random amount of time, then stops. For example, below is my attempts holding down some keys:

```
aaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa
a
b
bbbbbbbbbbb
b
ccccccccccc
cccccccccccccc
ccccc
```

On Windows on the same machine, the keyboard works fine. It also works on Ubuntu on another PC.

The problem is especially frustrating with the backspace key. I have to mash the key repeatedly to delete a few characters.

Things I tried so far:

- Restart computer
- Update and upgrade all packages
- Turn Repeat keys off and on
- Adjust Repeat keys' Delay and Speed
- Turn Bounce Keys on and off
- Upgrade kernel
- Change USB port
- Googling (a lot)

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/995819/touchpad-gestures-and-holding-keys-does-not-work/995948#995948

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su
echo "blacklist peaq_wmi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf
```

after which you must restsart.

[Key repeating doesn't work in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968192/key-repeating-doesnt-work-in-17-10?newreg=c394750026974260950c2fa36213cd62)