# Repeat key speed not saved

Tags: 20.04

I have gone into the accessibility settings and changed the repeat key speed and delay to be a tad quicker. However, I have noticed that on restarting sessions the settings appear to have changed (repeat keys is slower and with greater delay). When I look back in the accessibility settings, I see the sliders have not changed. If I move them away from and back to their original positions, expected behaviour is resumed. Why does this happen? Is ubuntu restoring defaults somehow?

Comment: I have this issue too. I have to do as @DJTS has done here, or disable and re-enable repeat keys. It happens for me after a suspend/resume. I tried to program it but  running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard delay 250` does not have any effect either. There's some [other options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81296/repeat-key-functionality-doesnt-work) posted back in 2011 but I've not tried those