# Keyboard autorepeat not working (18.04)

Tags: drivers, bug-reporting, autokey

Repeat keys functionality is not working, but auto-repeat is on:

```
▶  ~ $ xset q r
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  106    repeat rate:  43
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7fffffdffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  0/1    threshold:  3
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 180    Suspend: 0    Off: 300
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Some people encounter the same problems (i.e
[Repeat key functionality doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81296/repeat-key-functionality-doesnt-work#220138))
and make a reference to an issue with the driver `peaq-wmi`, however, I do not
seem to have this driver.

```
▶  ~ $ lmod | grep wmi
snd_rawmidi            40960  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd                    98304  21
snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_ts3a227e,snd_pcm_oss,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_mixer_oss
```

This all makes that I am stuck. What can I do to make auto repeat work on my
GalliumOS?

Kind regards,

Elzinus